# How do I populate a ComboBox within a ListView to display two items (true or false) and save changes to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, listview, combobox

[image]

The image demonstrates what I'm trying to do. There are **two columns** here, which have the same name(and representative of one column). I did that to demonstrate what I want to do.

I want to be able to populate the ComboBox in the ListView first of all, and secondly be able to save the chosen value to the database, which will either be true or false. Can someone please demonstrate for me how I can do that?

Comment: First of all this contains many topics from Xaml to Entity Framework, you will not find the answer in one question. Secondly you have shown no attempt at solving this yourself...

Comment: I have attempted.. I'm frustrated. I'm on the third day now. I just didn't see the need to post my efforts as I have failed dismally. But thank you for pointing me in the direction that I should go. I won't give up on it easily.

Comment: That's good, best of luck with figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `<ComboBox>` in xaml more specifically `SelectedItem`,`ItemSource` and `ItemTemplate`

Next look into Entity Framework and how you can use it to connect your `GridView` to your database.